# Great GUI for Apache2?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I wonder if there are great GUI management tools for Apache so you dont have to manually edit files in VIM.

It would be great if you could manage Apache over internet.

Any suggestions of such tools?

Comment: You should know that you can manually edit the config files in any text-editor of your choice.

Comment: hm but that was not what i wanted:) wanted a GUI or some kind of management tool to handle apache so i dont have to do same thing over and over again.

Comment: You can script things that you don't want to do over and over again. And adamse was suggesting other text editors, because many people find VI tedious when they are first learning.

Comment: Great? no. Usable? Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally-speaking, managing Apache over the Internet with a browser would be a bad thing unless properly secured.  Another problem is that a Web interface typically requires a web server running, which is a bit counter-productive if you're making changes to the web server itself.  This is why SSH + `<text editor of choice>` works so well -- you get the security of SSH and the robustness of `vi`.

Comment: Agreed. Any server admin worth his salt *needs* to know some CLI text editor (whether that be vi, emacs, whatever). After the initial learning curve, you'll find that you'll be able to make changes *much* more quickly from the CLI than you ever could using a GUI.

Answer (score 7):

I like [WEBMIN](http://www.webmin.com/).

Answer (score 3):

SSH plus the editor of your choice. Webmin will work, although it's incredibly clunky and ugly.

Like many others, I'm of the opinion that CLI is the only and proper way of doing some jobs and Apache configs fit into that class of job.

The thing about configs is that **you** need to be in charge, whether it's scripted or manual. Any interface I've tried for this kind of thing always changes the file into the format someone else thought it should be, rather than what I want. That just makes it harder to read and maintain, plus they often strip out the comments.

Answer (score 1):

http://gadmintools.flippedweb.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=45&Itemid=36

check this out it will help you setup using GUI